# configure: error: Can't find text2utt of festival in installing HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT

Tags: 16.04

I want to install **HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT** from http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp/

I installed **festival**, **sptk**, **hts**, **hts-engine** already
but when I config like this:

```
./configure --with-fest-search-path=/usr/local/festival/examples \
>                  --with-sptk-search-path=/usr/bin/ \
>                  --with-hts-search-path=/usr/local/HTS-2.3/bin \
>                  --with-hts-engine-search-path=/usr/local/hts_engine_API-1.10/bin
```

I get this error:

```
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for wc... /usr/bin/wc
checking for text2utt... :
configure: error: Can't find text2utt of festival
```

I will appreciate to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the script text2utt.sh as "text2utt" into HTS-demo_CMU-ARCTIC-SLT-STRAIGHT-AR-decision-tree/

https://github.com/zeehio/festival/blob/master/examples/text2utt.sh

Answer (score 0):

> configure: error: Can't find text2utt of festival

This error means your configuration cannot find text2utt file. Please make sure the path of festival search path is right.